# Going to IE8 with DOCTYPE HTML 4.01 Transitional

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8, doctype, html4

We use in all our pages in the 1st line of our HTML code the:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

We are moving on to the new IE8 and we would like to keep the DOCTYPE unchanged, is there any suggestions/warnings we better be aware of?

I mean like: "Be careful that CSS min-width is not working anymore in IE8 transitional, be careful that it will screw up page in this and that, etc."

Comment: You should post on http://doctype.com/ instead

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If your page works in IE7 and it works in the more standards-compliant browsers, chances are it'll work in IE8. IE8 gets closer to standards compliance; there aren't many significant regressions.

If your page only works in IE7, or works in IE7 (vs. the other browsers) by using a different code path that relies on IE7 bugs, you may have more work to do. You can in the meantime tell IE8 to behave similarly to IE7 by using the header/meta `X-UA-Compatible: EmulateIE7`.

Gory details of IE7/IE8 differences [at IEBlog](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2009/03/12/site-compatibility-and-ie8.aspx).